# How to find a td element that contains a h1 and then add an onclick event to the td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I need to add an onclick event in Jquery. This is the criteria- if a td contains an h1 element, it needs to be added to the next td after the h1 element. For example I have the below html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>Activity Packs</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><P>Test test Test test Test testTest test  Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test. Link: <a href="/products">I am a link</a></p></td>
    </tr>
```

The onclick event needs to be added to any "a" links instead the td after the h1 heading (the td with all the text text)

I don't have any control of the html so I can't add any id's or anything.

Comment: Can you write out what would be found in your example HTML and what it would be replaced with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('table h1').closest('tr').next().find('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2yd3g/1/

Or more effective:

```
$('table h1').closest('tr').next().on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
$('table tr td').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('h1')[0] != undefined){
     $($(this).find('h1')[0]).after('<a href="#">abc</a>');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$("td").each(function(){
if($(this).has("h1"){
$(this).next().append("click");
}
});